# Hortonworks HDFS Name Node tryLock issue on startup

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, namenode

We're using HDP HDFS module version 2.7.3.2.6.5.0-292.

The server was stuck and had to be hard-reseted - now the Name Node service throws an error upon start up.

After successfully acquiring a lock file, it instantaneously fails by trying to acquire it again, even through it's for the same process (presumably the same thread) - it fails.

How should we start the name node **with the data in tact**?

`18/11/14 20:19:24 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map NameNodeRetryCache
18/11/14 20:19:24 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
18/11/14 20:19:24 INFO util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory 1011.3 MB = 310.7 KB
18/11/14 20:19:25 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries
18/11/14 20:19:25 INFO common.Storage: Lock on /mnt/pd1/hadoop/hdfs/namenode/in_use.lock acquired by nodename 10635@hadoop-327
18/11/14 20:19:25 ERROR common.Storage: It appears that another node  10635@hadoop-327 has already locked the storage directory: /mnt/pd1/hadoop/hdfs/namenode
java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
        at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:255)
        at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(FileLockTable.java:152)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1113)
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.tryLock(Storage.java:770)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.lock(Storage.java:738)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.analyzeStorage(Storage.java:551)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.analyzeStorage(Storage.java:502)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that we had 2 paths that target the same directory at `dfs.namenode.name.dir`, which caused the double lock. Once we used a single path, everything was back to order.